# Numerically and Analytically Integrate an expression

Tags: calculus

HELP PLEASE!

I am looking for help with this part of a mock exam I have been given. If there is anyone willing to answer it that would be great! If you could include steps of how you got to the answer so that I can understand how to do it in future that would be most helpful. Thank you!

[image: mock test question]

Comment: You should try to post a self-contained, *specific* question. This is not the place for people to do your homework or exams for you. What exactly do you have problem with? What you have pasted here seems like an (incomplete!) excerpt containing several distinct parts. It is not at all clear what you are even asking about, and you have not shown any effort of your own.

Comment: Your help was really useful thanks :/ I have asked for help with the question because i'm unsure of how to work out the answer and I couldn't find help in previous asked questions. I'm studying for an exam and this is a previous paper question. As far as I can see I have added all of the information that I could from the information in the question on the paper.

Comment: But you gave no indication as to what it is exactly you're unsure of. I see several problems on this picture, and two of them are incomplete, and again, I see no indication on what you do and what you don't understand about it.

Comment: I'll post again with complete question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are doing likely involves the capacitance of a long cylindrical capacitor.
An excellent numerical approximation will be to take the points 4r = \left{ 1.00, 1.625, 2.25, 2.875, 3.50 \right} and use Simpson's rule:
$$
V \approx- \frac{0.4 \times 10^{-9}}{2\pi (8.854 \times 10^{-12}}\frac{1}{3} 0.625\times 10^{-3}  \left( \frac{10^3}{1.00}+4\frac{10^3}{1.625}+2\frac{10^3}{2.25}+4\frac{10^3}{2.875}+\frac{10^3}{3.500}\right)
$$
To do the integral analytically, not that the integral of $1/r$ is $\ln r$ so the answer is 
$$
V = \frac{0.4 \times 10^{-9}}{2\pi (8.854 \times 10^{-12}} \ln (3.5) $$

Comment: Thank you :) yes it was a coaxial cable and the power loss from the inner and outer conducter needed to be calculated. The gap being 1 - 3.5 between the two. I have looked everywhere for a worked example to copy and try and understand how to do it. Thanks again!